# How can i disable a TaskQueues or TaskRouter from the web

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I am using Twilio TaskRouter. And sometimes, i needed a way to stop a queue from functioning.
Is there a way to disable a TaskQueues or TaskRouter from the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To disable a queue from the Twilio console you could update the workflow so the expression that would match a queue always returns false. For example, by adding `AND 1 == 0` to the expression.

Since no tasks would match that expression, they would skip that queue and move to the next queue in the workflow.

Check out the documentation for more on [how workflows assign tasks to queues](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/lifecycle-task-workflows-and-assignment).